# Spark streaming with Kafka. Print statement prints out Bytes instead

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka

I'm Using Spark Streaming(1.6) with Kafka. I'm able to produce and receive the messages, But the messages from the `kafkaStream.pprint()` statement are displayed as the following.

```
(u'\x00\x00\x03\x13', u'Message_787')
(u'\x00\x00\x03\x14', u'Message_788')
(u'\x00\x00\x03\x15', u'Message_789')
(u'\x00\x00\x03\x16', u'Message_790')
(u'\x00\x00\x03\x17', u'Message_791')
```

#### Code:

```
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)   

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,"zookepper","consumer-group",{"TOPIC": 1})

kafkaStream.pprint()
```

How do i convert the messages to ASCII or human Readable format.